# Scrape data from link inside a link: Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I created a script that pulls data from the results pages of Michigan properties on Landwatch.com.
Here is my script:

```
import requests
from requests import get

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
           )
n_pages = 0
desc = []
for page in range(1,15000):
    n_pages += 1
    sapo_url = 'https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/Land/Page-' + str(page)
    r=get(sapo_url, headers=headers)
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    house_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_="propName")
    if house_containers != []:
        for container in house_containers:
            desc.append(container.getText(strip=True))
    else:
        break

print('you scraped {} pages containing {} Properties'.format(n_pages, len(desc)))



import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': desc}) 
import pyodbc
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=LAPTOP-5LE89UIK\MSSQLSERVER01;DATABASE=Dave;')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('Create TABLE Dave..Property1 (descrip varchar(max), Acreage float, Price money, City varchar(max), County varchar(max)), priceperacre float')
sql_conn.commit()

for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
             INSERT INTO Dave..Property1 (descrip)
             VALUES (?); 
            ''', 
            row.description
            )
sql_conn.commit

sql = ("Update Dave..Property1 SET Acreage = cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(descrip, 1, charindex('Acre', descrip, 1)), 'A', '') as float), "
       "Price = (CASE WHEN charindex('$', descrip) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE SUBSTRING(descrip, charindex('$', descrip), LEN(descrip)) END),"
       "City = CASE WHEN charindex(',', descrip) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE left(substring(descrip, charindex(' ', descrip) + 9, charindex(',', descrip)), "
        "                                       charindex(',', substring(descrip, "
                                                "charindex(' ', descrip) + 9, charindex(',', descrip))))"
                                                "END, "
                                             
                                                
        "COUNTY = CASE WHEN charindex(',', descrip) = 0 OR Charindex('$', descrip) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE "
        "REPLACE(SUBSTRING(descrip, charindex(',', descrip) + 1, charindex(', MI$', descrip) - charindex(',', descrip)), ',', '') END" 
       
       
       )

cursor.execute(sql)
sql_conn.commit()
sql_clean = ("Update Dave..Property1 SET CITY = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(CITY, ',', ''))), "
              "COUNTY = SUBSTRING(COUNTY, 1, (CASE WHEN charindex (',', COUNTY) = 0 THEN LEN(COUNTY) ELSE  " 
             "(charindex(',', COUNTY)-1) END))")
cursor.execute(sql_clean)
sql_conn.commit()   

sql_addperacre = ("UPDATE Dave..Property1 SET pricePerAcre = price / CASE WHEN Acreage = 0 OR acreage IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Acreage END")
cursor.execute(sql_addperacre) 
sql_conn.commit()

sql_removeCounty = ("Update Dave..Property1 SET COUNTY = REPLACE(County, 'County', '')")
cursor.execute(sql_removeCounty) 
sql_conn.commit()

sql_removeCountySpace = ("Update Dave..Property1 SET County = ltrim(rtrim(County))")
cursor.execute(sql_removeCountySpace) 
sql_conn.commit()

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotnine  import *

upSQL = ("SELECT pricePerAcre, city, county from dave..property1 WHERE COUNTY IN ('Alger', 'Marquette', 'DIckinson', 'Gogebic', 'Iron', 'Houghton', 'Ontonagon', 'Menominee', 'Delta', 'Schoolcraft', 'Luce', 'Mackinac', 'Chippewa')")
UPSQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(upSQL, sql_conn)
updf = pd.DataFrame(UPSQL_Query, columns=['pricePerAcre', 'city', 'county'])
ggplot(updf, aes(x= 'county', y= 'pricePerAcre', fill= 'county')) + geom_violin() + ylim(0, 10000)
# df.to_csv('test4.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
# df = pd.DataFrame(house_containers, columns = ['desc'])
# df.to_csv ('test.csv')
# print(df)
```

I'd like to expand my script to open the link of each property and extract the geographic coordinates which are embedded in each page.  Believe I need to create another script that opens each URL in a list (unique URLs have PIDs), but am unsure how to get started.  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To get coordinates of the property, you can parse google map URL inside `<iframe>`. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


for page in range(1, 10):
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    print()

    url = 'https://www.landwatch.com/Michigan_land_for_sale/Land/Page-{}'.format(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    
    for a in soup.select('.propName a'):
        prop_url = 'https://www.landwatch.com' + a['href']
        prop_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(prop_url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

        google_maps_url = prop_soup.select_one('#iframe-map iframe')

        print(prop_soup.h1.text)
        if google_maps_url:
            print(parse_qs(urlparse(google_maps_url['src']).query).get('q') )
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Marion, Osceola County, MI Land For Sale - 145 Acres
['44.0227,-85.1752']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nashville, Barry County, MI Land For Sale - 1.36 Acres
['42.5965,-85.09523']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrej.  This is the result I wanted . Now am having a problem getting output into a dataframe.  I posted this as a separate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122543/python-get-printed-output-into-dataframe

Thanks again!

Comment: It appears that the coordinates are not paired with the correct header description in the script.  Is there a way to make sure they correctly match? For instance, 44.0227 for the Marion Osceola County property here: https://www.landwatch.com/Osceola-County-Michigan-Land-for-sale/pid/338631254